# Problem using updateOne in an array with mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongodb-update

currently making an e-commerce application and trying to make the checkout api that will credit multiple stores with their respective amounts due. I'm sure the logic works because the history can be created properly but it appears the problem with the update part of the api is, it doesn't save and return the update value before running the loop again here's the source code

`

```
export default async function checkoutPayment(req, res) {
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        console.log('CONNECTING TO MONGO');
        await connectMongo();
        console.log('CONNECTED TO MONGO');


        const { sen, amt, mass_rec, pin, massCheck_id } = JSON.parse(req.body)

        const sender = await Student.findById(sen)





        //to get the orders in order
        const orders = await Promise.all((
            massCheck_id.map(async (check_id) => {
                return await CheckOutItem.findById(check_id)
            })
        ))









        // to get the stores for updating the account details
        const storeStruct = []

        for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
            storeStruct.push(await Seller.find({ storename: orders[i].storename }))
        }



        //get an ordered list of store ids
        const store_id = []
        for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
            store_id.push(await Seller.find({ storename: orders[i].storename }).select("_id"))
        }


        console.log(store_id[1])

        if (pin === sender.pin) {
            if (sender.account_bal > amt) {


                const new_store_bal = []


                let i = 0;
                //gets array ordered list of new account balances
                for (i = 0; i < storeStruct.length; i++) {
                    if (storeStruct[i][0].storename === orders[i].storename) {


                        new_store_bal.push(storeStruct[i][0].account_bal + orders[i].amount)
                    }

                }









                for (let i = 0; i < storeStruct.length; i++) {
                    console.log(storeStruct[i][0].account_bal + new_store_bal[i])


                    // supposed to credit the sellers accounts

                    const sled = await Promise.all((
                        store_id.map(async (id) => {
                            return await Seller.findById(id).updateOne({ account_bal: storeStruct[i][0].account_bal + new_store_bal[i] })
                        })
                    ))

                  

                    //creates history of transactions
                    const rec_history = await TransferHistory.create({
                        sender: sender.firstname + sender.lastname,
                        reciever: storeStruct[i][0].storename,
                        amount: new_store_bal[i],
                        trans_type: "CREDIT",
                        send_id: sen,
                        rec_id: storeStruct[i][0]._id
                    })




                }




                return res.status(200).json({ message: "successful" })



            } else {
                return res.status(256).json({
                    message: "insufficient funds",
                });

            }
        } else {
            return res.status(245).json({
                message: "incorrect pin"
            })
        }
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: "wrong request",
        });

    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The [UpdateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-updateOne) requires filter as first parameter and then the updateValues as second parameter. Since you are doing findById with updateOne this will perform two filters.

Use [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

```
const sled = await Promise.all((
  store_id.map(async (id) => {
      return await Seller.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{ account_bal: storeStruct[i][0].account_bal + new_store_bal[i] }, {new: true})
  })
))
```

`{new: true}` is added to return the updated document